# Background image and banner image in asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to set background picture of my webform.  I put the jpeg into my application folder.  When I tried to access it, it does not show the jpg while physical folder shows the image there.  Am I doing something wrong?  Please see the pic. and advise.

Thanks[image]

Comment: This folders are protected, try other names, other folders

Comment: Moved them all to another folder but imageurl property does not take me there.  I can not select anything outside project folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the image into the project for selecting via property sheets. VS will only show files present within your project (does not matter where it resides on the file system).
You can do that by either selecting "Add Existing Item" in right-click context menu on the project in solution explorer and browsing to your image file
OR
By using "Show All Files" icon at the top of solution explorer window and then selecting your image file in files tree and choosing "Include In Project" context menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !  but it did not work.  I added images to project, but when tried to select from imageurl, it does not show any of these.